# Another term for NEWBIES vs EXPERIENCED/PRO

Tags: synonyms

What's an interesting tagline or caption for a game (say like a reality game show) composed of newbies vs people who are not necessarily pro but have an experience with the game (or similar to it)

Things I have thought of:

- Contenders vs Champions
- Newbies vs Veterans
- David vs Goliath

Comment: EL&U deals with question that can be answered by citing authoritative references - questions that, in theory at least, have a single correct answer. This falls outside of that scope.

Comment: Aren't noobies and obies opposites?

Answer (score 1):

The Cambridge Dictionary defines [novice](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/novice) as "a person who is not experienced in a job or situation" and it is the word used almost universally before the comparatively recent invention of "newbie" which I, personally, rather dislike except in very informal settings.

I have posted this as an answer because you are new to EL&U but would advise you to at least enter *WORD synonym* (replacing WORD with the word you are asking about) into a search engine before asking a question like this again as we do expect you to do, and quote, research of your own before posting a question. Failure to do this often results in questions being closed for lack of research.

If you type "newbie synonym" into Google for example (other search engines are available) you will be presented with quite a long list of words, including "novice" and I prefer most of them to "newbie", although some are rather specialised.